# VBA: Create selected string from an array

Tags: arrays, vba, powerpoint, do-while

EDIT: Thanks in advance for your help. I'd like to loop through an array and create a string based on until a condition is no longer met. I think my current code creates an infinite loop.

I have the following in an array (subsections start with "- "). NB please ignore the quote marks - dashes format to bullets so had to put these in to stop that.

"- Subsection2"

"- Subsection3"

"Second Section"

"- Subsection4"

"Third Section"

"- Subsection5"

I would like to create a new string which stores *only* those strings/array slots that start with "-" until and excluding the next one that does not start with "-". The resultant string I want is:

"- Subsection1"

"- Subsection2"

"- Subsection3"

(and excluding "- Subsection 4" and "- Subsection 5")

Essentially I want the remaining subsections that are within the same 'master' section.

Below is my attempt at this:

```
Dim testArray() As Variant
Dim count1 As Integer
Dim CurrentSectionIndex as Integer

CurrentSectionIndex = ActivePresentation.Slides(i).sectionIndex



    count1 = ActivePresentation.SectionProperties.Count - CurrentSectionIndex


    'clear previous array (I am looping through slides)
    Erase testArray
    ' size the array

    ReDim testArray(1 To count1)


    'Fill the array


    For n = 1 To count1

        testArray(n) = ActivePresentation.SectionProperties.Name(CurrentSectionIndex + n)

        Next n


            Dim AllPostSections As String
            Dim PostSections As String


            For m = LBound(testArray) To UBound(testArray)

            Do While testArray(m) Like "-*"
            PostSections = testArray(m)

            Loop   

            AllPostSections = AllPostSections & PostSections & vbNewLine
            Next m
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The while loop you want to achieve is being done by the For m loop.  You need to replace your current do while with an if statement e.g. If test array(m) Like ("-*") then  :PostSections=PostSections & testarray(m): End if.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response Freeflow- though won't that mean I also catch subsections 4 and 5? I thought I needed to use do while/until so it terminates after the first instance

Comment: You are confused about what a Do Loop is.  I'd suggest you look for some basic tutorials on VBA and read up on For Next and Do Loops.You may need to update your post to be clearer about what you want to capture and what you do not.  At the moment its indicating you want to capture every heading starting with  '-' . If you want to capture only those headings between Headings that do not start with a - that's a different set of code.

Comment: Sorry - you're right my question wasn't as clear as it should've been. I've edited now - hopefully it's clearer. Yes I only want to capture headings starting with "-" until the next one that doesn't. I've read up quite a lot on For Next and Do Loops and thought that either Do While or Do Until would be the right solution as they terminate after a condition is no longer met/or until a condition is met and so would terminate at the first non "-" heading and therefore not consider the following "-" headings, but maybe I'm wrong on that. I'd really appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your basic assumption about why you would use a Do While/Until loop is correct but your implementation is incorrect.  For the task you are trying to achieve its not necessary to use a Do While loop as the looping you need is the For M loop.  Then within the For loop all you need to do is to test using an If statement to assemble the string you want.  If you wanted you could replace the for next loop with a Do while loop but in fact its much easier to achieve what you want using collections.  You can index items in a collection int he same way as an array so unless you look at the variable definition you can tell if my_array(1) is using an array or a collection.

The code below will take a collection of all your headings (test array) and produce a new collection where you only have concatenated subheadings.

```
Option Explicit

Dim my_headings                         As Collection
Dim my_heading                          As Variant
Dim my_subheadings                      As Collection
Dim my_collector                        As String

my_collector = vbNullString
' fill the my_heading collection
Set my_subheadings = New Collection

For Each my_heading In my_headings

    If my_heading Like "-*" Then

        my_collector = my_collector & my_heading & vbCrLf

    Else

        If Len(my_collector) > 0 Then

            my_sub_headings.Add my_collector
            my_collector = vbNullString

        End If

    End If

Next
```

Edited: Here is the same logic as above but with the for next loop replaced with a do while loop.  Hopefully this will clarify your rather confused ides of what a do While loop does.

```
Dim my_headings                         As Collection
Dim my_subheadings                      As Collection
Dim my_collector                        As String
Dim my_index                            As Long
my_collector = vbNullString
' fill the my_heading collection
Set my_subheadings = New Collection

my_index = 1

Do While my_index <= my_headings.Count

    If my_headings(my_index) Like "-*" Then

        my_collector = my_collector & my_heading & vbCrLf

    Else

        If Len(my_collector) > 0 Then

            my_sub_headings.Add my_collector
            my_collector = vbNullString

        End If

    End If

    my_index=my_index+1

Loop
```

Comment: Thanks Freeflow -  I'm not quite sure how an If statement will cut out subsections 4 and 5 but I'll give this a go along with trying Do While as a loop and see how I go.

Comment: In the example above you get a new collection called my_sub_headings.  After the for loop has completed you will have at least three entries in that collection (based upon the example you provide).  my_sub_headings(1)will be -Subsection1 + subsection2+subsection3, my_sub_headings(2) will be -Subsection4, my_sub_headings(3) will be -subsection5 etc

Comment: @RichardWallace.  I've edited by answer to add an example for a do while loop.

Comment: That is awesome - thanks so much for your help Freeflow. I finally understand how you did this. Much to learn...